# Reconciling the Alternative Definitions of Matrix Rank in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, machine-learning, matrix-rank

I was working out the definitions of matrix rank while trying to understand the [Manifold Mixup](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/verma19a/verma19a.pdf) paper & found myself with the below quandry:

(A) For an 5x3 matrix , the row rank must equal the column rank. Which appeared to mean  the maximum value the rank can take is 3, because there are only 3 columns so the number of basis vectors of the column space could presumably not be greater.
(B) Alternatively, according my understanding of [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)), rank can also be defined as the dimensions of its image if a matrix is a linear transformation.
(C)  If you use a 5x3 matrix A to transform a 3x1 vector v, you get a 5x1 vector Av. The dimensions of the image is 5x1, so from (B) the rank is 5, but from (A) the rank can at most be 3 giving an apparent contradiction.

Could someone please tell me where I am getting this wrong? I suspect the issue is coming from a confusion of the definitions of rank? But I can't quite pinpoint it.

I would greatly appreciate the assistance.

Comment: You will get 5x1 vectors, but there will only be “three dimensions” of such vectors. Among those 5x1 vectors you can find at most 3 linearly independent.

Comment: so essentially the number of basis vectors in the image, as opposed to the dimensionality of each vector, warm thanks! ^.^

Answer (score 2):

Your claims are correct, the deductions are not.

While you are right in pointing out that rank of a matrix is the dimensions of image space of the corresponding linear transformation, the fact that a matrix transforms vectors to $\mathrm{R}^5$ is not sufficient to claim that the image space is 5-dimensional. It merely says that the image space is a sub-space of $\mathrm{R}^5$.

Dimensions are only defined for vector spaces. A singleton vector, for that matter, does not constitute a vector space, and hence does not have a dimension, per say. We can say, though, that a singleton vector belongs to $\mathrm{R}^n$ for some $n$, which **is** a vector space, and thus has a dimension (here, $n$).

In this particular scenario, the fact that rank of a $5 \times 3$ matrix, call $A$, cannot be greater than three has a pretty intuitive explanation. 
Since $A$ encodes a linear transformation, which by definition cannot be one-to-many, and has domain $\mathrm{R}^3$, the image space cannot possible have a dimension greater than the domain. (in some sense, this corresponds to having more number of output vectors than number of inputs, which is absurd)
Thus,
$$ dim(Im(A)) \leq dim(\mathrm{R}^3) = 3$$
$$ rank(A) \leq 3$$

Hope this helps !